# How to show numbers as super script on a gobject app indicator icon?

Tags: python, gtk3, gnome, pygobject, gobject

I have a working app indicator that looks something like this i.e text as label beside the app indicator icon -
[image]
I wanted to know if it is possible to get it to look like this i.e number on the icon as a superscript-
[image]
Sample code for the app indicator -

```
import random
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator

APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def cb_exit(w, data):
   Gtk.main_quit()

def change_label(ind_app):
    t = random.randint(1,6)
    print(t)
    ind_app.set_label(str(t) , '')

ind_app = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, Gtk.STOCK_INFO, appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
ind_app.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)

# create a menu
menu = Gtk.Menu()
menu_items = Gtk.MenuItem("Exit")
menu.append(menu_items)
menu_items.connect("activate", cb_exit, '')
menu_items.show_all()
ind_app.set_menu(menu)
GLib.timeout_add(1000, change_label, ind_app)
Gtk.main()
```

If it is indeed possible, then how?